# Add-Type doesn't support dictionary initialization syntax?

Tags: c#, powershell

The following code gets the error of

> Add-Type : c:\Users....cs(7) : Invalid expression term '['
>
> c:\Users.....cs(6) :         return new Dictionary{
>
> c:\Users.....cs(7) : >>>             ["aa"] = "123",
>
> c:\Users.....cs(8) :             ["bb"] = "235"

```
$Source = @"
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class BasicTest
{
  public static Dictionary<string, string> Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, string>{ 
            ["aa"] = "123",
            ["bb"] = "235"
        };
    }
  public int Multiply(int a, int b)
    {
    return (a * b);
    }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source
```

Answer (score 0):

When I run `help Add-Type`, one of the options is:

`[-Language {CSharp | CSharpVersion3 | CSharpVersion2 | VisualBasic | JScript}]`

It only has options going up to C# 3.0, which came with .NET 3.5. The syntax it's breaking on is using a feature from C# 6.0.

Note: my version of Powershell is 5.1, which came with Windows and predates the current open-source Powershell: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell . I'll bet your example will work with a more recent release.